# UISliders inside different UITableViewCells affect each other when continuous

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uislider

I have made a UITableView with some cells containing UISliders. Every UISlider has a unique tag - the number of a value it represents.

When isContinuous value is set to true for them, the first and the last sliders affect each other - dragging one of them makes the same change in value on the other.
Here is how those cells are made:

```
class CellWithSliderValues: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider! = {
        let ctrl = UISlider()
        ctrl.backgroundColor = Constants.SETTINGS_CELL_COLOR
        return ctrl
    }()
    // some labels
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // layout
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        slider.tag = -10
        minLabel.text = nil
        maxLabel.text = nil
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

```
internal func makeSignalLevelCell(\*some args*\) -> UITableViewCell{
        let tag: Int
        let currValue: Float
        let minValue, maxValue: Float
        switch(kind){
        \\ set all the values above
        }
        if (numInSection == 0){
            // other cells
        } else{
            let cell = mainScreen.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellWithSliderValues") as! CellWithSliderValues
            cell.slider.maximumValue = maxValue
            cell.slider.minimumValue = minValue
            cell.slider.value = currValue
            cell.minLabel.text = Int(minValue).description
            cell.maxLabel.text = Int(maxValue).description
            cell.slider.tag = tag
            cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChange), for: .valueChanged)
            return cell
        }
```

```
@objc func sliderChange(sender: UISlider){
        guard let valueToAdjustNumber = HeatmapSettings.RangedValueOption(rawValue: sender.tag) else {print("Non-understood slider"); return}
        print (valueToAdjustNumber)
        let newValueGiven = sender.value
        switch(valueToAdjustNumber){
        \\check for validity and save changes to a different variable
        }
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
        mainScreen.table.reloadData() // beacuse we need to refresh the number in text box
    }
```

The first and the last sliders in the table affect each other - when one has its value adjusted, the other changes its value too. With some debug outputs - see the

```
print (valueToAdjustNumber)
```

line above - it looks like valueToAdjustNumber alternates between the one expected for the slider and the one affected by the glitch.

It is not the problem of cell reuse - I tried genereting new cells instead of reuse, and also reusing cells but recreating sliders, it did not help.

When .isContinuous is set to false for the sliders, the problem disappears.

Comment: In your cell class, you show an `@IBOutlet` slider... is that connected to a prototype cell? If so, is there a reason you are creating a new instance for that var? Is there a reason you're calling `.resignFirstResponder()` on the slider? Are you sure you're setting your `.tag` correctly? Are you sure you're updating your data correctly? Is there a reason you're calling `table.reloadData()` ***every time a slider is moved*** (instead of updating only the *"number in text box"* ?

Comment: Can you clarify the first question, I did not understand that.
Yes, I am setting .tag correctly, I checked 3 times.
Yes, there is a reason I reload - if I try to only reload a part of the table, the section headers switch to the view ending in "...", like they are too long.
Removing .resignFirstResponder() on the slider does not change anything.

Comment: Also - is there a good way to reload only the cell with a target text box from the function called on slider move?
The slider can be in the second cell of the sections with index 1, 2 or 3. The text box that has to be updated is in in the first cell of the same section.

Comment: OK - try to better explain what you are doing... your post didn't say anything about updating other cells... it also sounded like you have several cells with sliders, and dragging the first slider causes the last slider to move? Strip your code down to only what is needed and put together a [mre]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: OK - then you are almost ***certainly*** updating your data incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug disappeared after reloading only one section at a time.

```
mainScreen.table.reloadData()
```

Is made into

```
mainScreen.table.reloadSections([sectionNumberToReload(value: valueToAdjustNumber)], with: .none)
```

Comment: If that fixed the issue, great... but I strongly suspect that if you scroll the table, when the slider rows are scrolled back into view you'll still see incorrect data.